# SQL Server SELECT statement compare time in db with current time

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is probably a noob question, but i am a little stuck.

I have this long SELECT query :

```
SELECT  
    dbo.Dagplanning.GeldigOp ,
    dbo.Trips_Bus.Route ,
    dbo.Trips_Bus.TripStart AS BeginUur ,
    dbo.Places.Naam AS BeginPlaats ,
    dbo.Trips_Bus.TripEnd AS EindUur ,
    dbo.Trips_Bus.Duty AS Dienst ,
    dbo.Trips_Bus.Block ,
    dbo.Personeel.Personeelsnummer ,
    dbo.Personeel.Naam ,
    dbo.Personeel.VoorNaam ,
    dbo.Trips_Bus.OpDay ,
    dbo.Trips_Bus.PeriodeID
FROM    
    dbo.Dagplanning ,
    dbo.Personeel ,
    dbo.Trips_Bus ,
    dbo.Places
WHERE   
    dbo.Trips_Bus.TripStart >= DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, -5, GETDATE()), 0)
    AND dbo.Trips_Bus.TripStart <= DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 300, GETDATE()), 0)
    AND dbo.Personeel.Personeelsnummer = dbo.Dagplanning.Personeelsnummer
    AND dbo.Trips_Bus.Duty = ( dbo.Dagplanning.Rol + '+' + REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(dbo.Dagplanning.Dienst)) + dbo.Dagplanning.Dienst )
    AND dbo.Trips_bus.Opday LIKE '%" + opdag + "%'
    AND dbo.Trips_Bus.PeriodeID = '" + periodeid + "'
    AND dbo.Dagplanning.GeldigOp = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    AND dbo.Trips_Bus.TripFrom = dbo.Places.Place
ORDER BY 
    dbo.Trips_Bus.TripStart ASC
```

It's actually this part that I have a problem with:

```
WHERE 
    dbo.Trips_Bus.TripStart >= DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, -5, GETDATE()), 0) 
    AND dbo.Trips_Bus.TripStart <= DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 300, GETDATE()), 0)
```

This returns nothing, no error but also no data. De data in the table is stored like this example : 21:50:00

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Please be gentle ;-)

Oh, I am completely new at this, so please keep that in mind!

Comment: What is the data type of `TripStart`? Is it really a string containing just a time-of-day? Try `select DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, -5, GETDATE()), 0)` and see what you get.

Comment: Eek. Carriage returns and tabs are your friend. Do you ever go back and read your own code?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: God what a mess that code was! You need to **(a)** learn to format your SQL in a **readable way** - or **(b)** at least use an online [SQL formatter service](http://sqlformat.appspot.com/) to format your SQL nicely so other folks can actually **READ IT!**

Comment: The data type is just a string containing just a time of day. 
I tried `SELECT DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, -5, GETDATE()), 0)`
The result is `2013-12-22 11:12:00.000`. 
Note the fact that the 'date' is changing, the time remains the current time.

Comment: When i use `-5`, the date goes up and with `10` it goes 10 days back.

Comment: Dunno if it helps but i am using MS SQL server 2008

Comment: Okay, now you know you are comparing (alphabetically) a string containing a time to a string containing a date and time. How do you plan to get rid of the date? Cast as `TIME`? Cast as `VARCHAR` and take a substring?

Comment: First you need to CONVERT that string to a date value like so: SELECT CONVERT(datetime ,'11:11:11 PM') output : 1900-01-01 11:11:11.0000   

Then add today's date, just the date portion, using DATEADD()  

Finally you can compare the converted TripStart value to GETDATE() using DATEDIFF.